# Facebook OAUTH2 javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I have upgraded my application to  use new Javascript SDK for OAuth2 upgrade as listed in developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/, but I am getting weired  Facebook error "An error occurred.Please try again later" on the  Facebook login page after  hitting login page with login credentials.

I didn't find any error on the network trace and there is no clue about this error.It will be greately appreciated if someone can  give pointers to debug this issue or  if anyone has encountered similar problem, then please help me to resolve this issue.

Here is the REST call which is client making

Once I click ,'Login with Facebook' button  from My application:

https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key='MYAPPID'&skip_api_login=1&display=popup&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2FMYDOMAIN.COM%2FContent%2Fchannel.html%3Ffb_xd_fragment%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.%23%3F%3D%26cb%3Df2f3b7c4e9caeee%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dfragment%26frame%3Dfb9a67b65014ef&fbconnect=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3DMYAPPID%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252FMYDOMAIN.COM%252FContent%252Fchannel.html%253Ffb_xd_fragment%2523%253F%253D%2526cb%253Df2f3b7c4e9caeee%2526relation%253Dopener%2526transport%253Dfragment%2526frame%253Dfb9a67b65014ef%26sdk%3Djoey%26display%3Dpopup%26response_type%3Dtoken%252Csigned_request%26domain%3DMYDOMAIN.COM%26fbconnect%3D1%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1

Click the login button,After entering credentials :

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id='MYAPPID'&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%MYAPPLICATION.COM%2FContent%2Fchannel.html%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23%3F%3D%26cb%3Df29a5b7a0e0cc6a%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dfragment%26frame%3Df2510bc146971d4&sdk=joey&display=popup&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&domain=MyApplicationDomain&fbconnect=1&from_login=1

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your url [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

And also [whole procedure by oauth2 jsdk with example](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/)